# How to deploy an update of a windows 8 lob/enterprise-app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, sccm, sideloading, line-of-business-app

I've just completed an update for an lob-app, but when I try to deploy it as an update I get the error `ERROR_PACKAGE_ALREADY_EXISTS (0x80073CFB)`. When I searched for this error I found the following error details:

> The provided package is already installed, and reinstallation of the package is blocked.
>
> You may get this error if installing a package that is not bitwise identical to the package that is already installed. Note that the digital signature is also part of the package. Hence if a package is rebuilt or resigned, it is no longer bitwise identical to the previously installed package.  Two possible options to fix this error are: (1) Increment the version number of the app, then rebuild and resign the package (2) Remove the old package for every user on the system before installing the new package.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx)

Indeed the package was resigned and a new certificate was used but I even incremented the version number.

Is there another way to deploy an update without having to uninstall the previous version first? If I got it right, every change in the app code or even every change of the certificate will result in an different package. That seems to be logical for me. I even incremented the version number from `1.0.0.1` to `1.1.0.0`, rebuild and resigned it. But this doesn't seam to be enough.. still getting the `error_package_already_exists`:((

Comment: I found out that the error reason was the new certificate. Signing with the initial cert, the app could be updated smoothly. Probably the certificate key is part of the deployment identity which prevents the app from updating ..

Comment: You should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The update works fine if the same certificate is used for signing the new version, which was used for signing the installed version. By using a different certificate you have to uninstall the previous version first.